# Reading python variables during a running job

Tags: python, shell

I have launched a python script that takes a long time to finish, and silly me I forgot to print out the values of important variables every now and then in my script, to for example estimate the progress of the computation I'm doing. 
So now, I was wondering if there's a way to access the current values of certain set of variables in my code (e.g. a list), as the script is running? (I could of course just stop it and add the changes/prints to the code then relaunch, but since it has been running for a day now, it is a pity to lose the computed values so far)

Alternatively, can I crash it in a certain way (other than usual Ctrl-c keyboard interrupt) such that the variable values at the moment of crash are pasted somewhere given that I didn't plan for this in my script? (I am running Ubuntu, python 2.7 and the script is simply run from a terminal by 'python test.py')

Comment: Note - in the future *always* use the `logging` module vs. print statements. If you get in that habit, you'll always be dumping out data. If you get to a point where you really don't care, you can turn down the logging level so it only shows warning/exception messages (or nothing at all).

Comment: @WayneWerner Thanks a lot for the tip, indeed you're absolutely right. I feel so sad and silly right now...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without editing your program, you're going to have a bad time. What you are looking for is some form of remote debugger, but anything that gives you python specific things will probably have to be at least somehow given a hook into your program. That being said, if you feel like fiddling around in a stack, you can attach gdb to your program (`gdb -p <PID>`) and see what you can find.

Edit: Well. This might actually be possible.

Following [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb), with the python extentions for GDB installed, if you pop open a gdb shell with `gdb python <PID>`, you should be able to run `py-print <name of the variable>` to get its value, assuming it's in the scope of the program at that point.
Attempting to do this myself, with the trivial program

```
import time
a = 10
time.sleep(1000)
```

I was able to open a GDB shell by finding the PID of the program (`ps aux | grep python`), running `sudo gdb python <PID>` and then run `py-print a`, which produced "global 'a' = 10". Of course this assumes you are running in a *nix environment.

Tawling around in the GDB shell for a while, I found you can actually interact with the Python primatives. For example, to get the length of an array:

```
(gdb) python-interative
>>>  frame = Frame.get_selected_python_frame()
>>>  pyop_frame = frame.get_pyop()
>>>  var, scope = pyop_frame.get_var_by_name('<variable name>')
>>>  print(var.field('ob_size'))
```

Note the requirement to use the actual internal field names to get things (The actual values of the list can be found with 'ob_item', and then an index).

You can dump the array to a file in a similar way:

```
length = int(str(var.field('ob_size'))
output = []
for i in range(length):
    output.append(str(var[i]))
with open('dump', 'w') as f:
    f.write(', '.join(output))
```

Comment: I like the gdb idea, thanks. Can you please give me some rope as to how I can use gdb to access a certain variable? (in a dummy example so I can see the idea)

Comment: @user929304 That's the problem here. Without adding specific hooks into your program, any information about what bits of memory map to what variables is effectively lost. GDB will give you a dump of the memory which about the best you'll be able to do.

Comment: BRILLIANT! I think you've cracked it, well done! So I could print the list i wanted using py-print, but it truncates the print output as it is a very large list. Is there a way to get the length of the list instead of printing it? a simpl py-print len(ls) doesn't work.

Comment: @user929304 So the maximum output length is defined in python2.7-gdb.py (Mine was at /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python2.7-gdb.py). In particular the value MAX_OUTPUT_LENGTH. If you edit that value to something very large and then reopen GDB `py-print` should give you the full value, which you can pipe to a file or something.

Comment: Ah I see. So if I understand correctly, within gdb, other than printing using py-print one cannot run other commands, e.g. py-len() or something of that kind, or is there a way?

Comment: @user929304 It's possible, but janky  - see my edit.

Comment: from where to import 'Frame' ?